# How to figure out what is the gateway and interface in routing table

Tags: networking, routing, gateway, interface

So I've got this simple yet very confusing at least for me problem, to determine what is the interface and ip next gateway from a router to network. Lets say we got setup like this -

[image: Diagram] .

And if I want to set the route from router R1 to network `172.31.10.0/24`, the next ip gateway is `172.31.10.2` with interface `e0`, 1 hop, or I am mistaken?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very confusing question.
If you have a router connecting with your ISP which would forward your traffic to a desired destination, that would be a next-hop "gateway".

So for example, if you have on R1
Ethernet0
Ip address 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.252

!
interface vlan1
ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip route 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.2
your ISP should have another interface against you with

interface X
ip address 10.10.10.2 255.255.255.252

Then it depends on where the traffic from 192.168.30.0/24 should end.

If you have a computer behind vlan1 on R1, the default-gateway for that computer should be 192.168.30.1 (vlan1) your router R1 would then forward that traffic to your ISP and your ISP would forward that traffic to a desired location.

This is a normal setup for branches. If you have a pure internet connection, you would forward your traffic to the outside interface (ATM0/ETH0/DIALER0..ETC)

Based on the confusion regarding this question I have no idea if that satisfies your needs, if not please provide a more detailed question.

thanks